# why is cv.glmnet parallel=TRUE not working

Tags: glmnet, doparallel

I am trying run glmnet cross validation in parallel. Elapsed time between parallel and not parallel versions show no considerable difference

I have tried with both Windows 7 enterprise laptop (8 cores) and Windows server (24 cores).

```
library(doParallel)
library(glmnet)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
print(no_cores)
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

x = matrix(rnorm(1e5 * 300), 1e5, 300)
y = rnorm(1e5)
system.time(cv.glmnet(x,y,parallel=TRUE))  # this is parallel
stopCluster(cl)
system.time(cv.glmnet(x,y))                # not parallel
```

this is parallel

```
   user  system elapsed 
  18.16   46.76   79.45
```

not parallel

```
system.time(cv.glmnet(x,y))                
   user  system elapsed 
  75.36    2.75   78.10
```